# Set "compiler" option from .vimrc

Tags: vim, ftplugin

I am using Vim 8.2 on Windows 10.

I have a custom compiler plugin called `msbuild` which I use to build a single C++ file. Each time I work on a new file, I must type:

```
:compiler msbuild
```

to make sure my `msbuild` compiler plugin is loaded, otherwise `make` fails. It's very annoying. I can type:

```
:compiler! msbuild
```

to set it globally, but then it is set for all files, even non C++ ones. I'd like my `msbuild` compiler plugin to be *automatically* loaded when I start working a new C++ file (extension :`.cpp`). I have tried using `autocmd` with `FileType` with no success:

```
autocmd FileType cpp compiler msbuild
```

I did not find a working example using Google. How can I achieve this?

Comment: `filetype plugin on` and the ftplugin: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+ftplugin+%22c%2B%2B%22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your autocommand probably fails because you didn't enable filetype detection and/or filetype plugins. Adding the following line to your `vimrc` should get you out of trouble:

```
filetype plugin on
```

If you also want filetype-specific indenting (you probably should) you can use this line instead:

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

If, somehow, you don't want to enable filetype detection, you can condition your autocommand on the file extension:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.cpp compiler msbuild
```

That said, the most canonical way to deal with the problem at hand, which is what @phd hinted at, is to…

1. Enable filetype detection, plugins, and indenting in your `vimrc` with:

   ```
   filetype plugin indent on
   ```
2. Create a custom ftplugin:

   ```
   %userprofile%\vimruntime\after\ftplugin\cpp.vim
   ```
3. With the following content:

   ```
   compiler msbuild
   ```